# Minister vs. Secretary

Tags: word-choice, terminology

In English language, the government structure of all countries is referred to with the terms of minister and ministry.

However, in English-speaking countries, Secretary and Department are used instead.

UK/US Secretary of State at UK/US Department of State.

Despite this terminology, the head of secretaries in the UK is still called Prime Minister (not Prime Secretary).

Why in English speaking countries, the terms ministry and minister are avoided for the government structure?

Comment: I was surprised to learn that the UK Govt. is just down to the Ministry of Defense and Ministry of Justice; the rest of them have been renamed Department, as you point out. Only other note is that many US governmental departments are named Bureau or Agency and typically have a Director. All that to say is that I don't think there's an intelligible pattern at work, just legislators going with what sounds fashionable. After all, nothing can get done in business or government without a [cool name](http://www.theonion.com/video/congress-struggles-to-come-up-with-cool-name-for-a-14249).

Comment: *Minister/Ministry* has always been avoided in the US because when our country was established *minister* still had the overtone of being an appointment of the monarch personally.

Comment: @Patrick: It is still the _Ministry_ of Silly Walks!

Comment: I have no idea why the British moved away from "minister/ministry", but StoneyB explains it well for the US.

Comment: @PatrickM US governmental *departments* (i.e. cabinet-level organizations) are all called "Department," and all of them except Justice are led by a "Secretary" (Justice is led by the Attorney General). Bureaus and Agencies are either below a Department in the org chart, or are outside the whole departmental structure; their heads are not cabinet officials and aren't called "minister" or "secretary."

Comment: The UK Government has the Ministry of Defence (with a C) and [23 other Ministerial Departments](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations) which are mainly Departments and not Ministries. The Ministry of Transport still lives on in the [MOT test](https://www.gov.uk/getting-an-mot), though. There are a large number of non-ministerial departments, executive agencies and other public bodies. There doesn't appear to be any rhyme or reason to it.

Comment: FWIW, I don't understand your first sentence, "*In English language, the government structure of all countries are referred to with the terms of minister and minister.*" I have no idea what you mean, even if I try to guess past the redundant occurrences of *minister*.

Comment: @Drew I mean in English language, each unit of other governments is called ministry, but in English speaking countries, each unit of the government is called Department with a Secretary. Why English speaking people use the term ministry for other governments, but Department for their own governments.

Comment: It may just be an attempt to provide a more faithful translation of the words used in those other countries. For example, France calls their government departments _ministrés_, so it's translated to _ministry_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about historical choice rather than implicit language change.

Answer (score 5):

The system of nomenclature is unique from government to government, and the terminology of the United States government was established with the expressed purpose of differentiating from the monarchial system in England when Independence was gained. In the United States the *[Federal Government](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_government_of_the_United_States)* is divided into three branches:

**1. [*Legislative Branch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_government_of_the_United_States#Legislative_branch)**

> The United States Congress is the legislative branch of the federal
> government. It is bicameral, comprising the House of Representatives
> and the Senate.
>
> *Wikipedia.org*

- A members of The House of Representatives is **called** *[congressman](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/congressman)* or *[congresswoman](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/congresswoman)*:

> *congressman*
>
> noun (plural congressmen)
>
> A member of Congress, especially a member of the US House of
> Representatives:
>
> *congresswoman*
>
> noun (plural congresswomen)
>
> A female member of Congress, especially a female member of the US
> House of Representatives:
>
> *ODO*

- A member of the Senate is **called** *[senator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/senator)*:

> noun
>
> 1 A member of a senate, in particular a member of the US Senate:
>
> *ODO*

---

**2. [*Executive Branch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_government_of_the_United_States#Executive_branch)**

> The executive power in the federal government is vested in the
> President of the United States, although power is often delegated to
> the Cabinet members and other officials.
>
> *Wikipedia.org*

- The Chief Executive Officer is **called** *[president](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/president?q=President)*:

> noun
>
> 1 The elected head of a republican state:
>
> *ODO*

- The President's replacement is called **called** *[vice president](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vice-president)*:

> noun
>
> An official or executive ranking below and deputizing for a president:
>
> *ODO*

- The President appoints a *[cabinet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_of_the_United_States)* of unelected officials, including **fifteen** people who oversee the details of *[federal executive departments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_federal_executive_departments)*.
- With the exception of the *[Attorney General](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/attorney-general?q=attorney%20general)*, each head of a federal executive department is **called** *[Secretary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/secretary)* of [Specific Name of Department]:

> 1.3 An official in charge of a US government department.

- Each federal executive department is organized with **Bureaus**, **Agencies** and **Administrations**, as well as numerous other smaller subsections of executive responsibility.
- The leaders of these subsections are predominantly called *director*:

> noun
>
> 1 A person who is in charge of an activity, department, or
> organization:
>
> *ODO*

---

**3. Judicial Branch**

> The Judiciary explains and applies the laws. This branch does this by
> hearing and eventually making decisions on various legal cases.
>
> *Wikipedia.org*

- Each member of the judiciary is **called** *[justice](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/justice)*:

> 2 A judge or magistrate, in particular a judge of the Supreme Court of
> a country or state.
>
> *ODO*

- The presiding member of the Supreme Court is called the *[Chief Justice](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chief-justice?q=chief%20justice)*:

> 1.1 (Chief Justice of the United States) (The formal title of) the chief justice of the US Supreme Court.
>
> *ODO*